# Stackbased buffer overrun

Tags: c++, buffer, external, stack-based, overrun

When running my code I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00BA16A0 in GameLauncher.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

I have no idea what could be causing this.  It is caused with the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Which process would you like to close? (Include .exe)" << std::endl;
    wchar_t userProcessToFind;
    std::wcin.getline(&userProcessToFind, 20);

    HANDLE processSnapshot;
    DWORD processID = 0;
    PROCESSENTRY32 processEntery;
    processEntery.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    processSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, processID);
    if(Process32First(processSnapshot, &processEntery) == TRUE)
    { 

        while (Process32Next(processSnapshot, &processEntery) == TRUE)
        {
            if (_wcsicmp(processEntery.szExeFile, &userProcessToFind) == 0)
            {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, processEntery.th32ProcessID);

                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
wchar_t userProcessToFind;
std::wcin.getline(&userProcessToFind, 20);
```

You have allocated space for a single `wchar_t` but you are trying to read in up to 20 characters and place it in the memory at the address of `userProcessToFind`.  This will cause stack corruption as you are going to try to write into memory that does not belong to `&userProcessToFind`.  What you need to do is create an array like

```
wchar_t userProcessToFind[20];
std::wcin.getline(userProcessToFind, 20);
```

Or you could use a [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and your code would become

```
std::wstring userProcessToFind;
std::getline(std::wcin, userProcessToFind);
```

This gives the benefit of not having to use an arbitrary size for the process name as `std::wstring` will scale to fit the input.  If you need to pass the underlying `wchar_t*` to a function you can use [`std::wstring::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't even thinking about that. You just saved me a lot of trouble :)